# No signing table match for <user@gmail.com> in OpenDKIM configuratio

Tags: debian, postfix, sql, opendkim

I have a problem with my opendkim configuration.
I have the alias ciao@mrtsolutions.it that forward all to mymail@gmail.com.
When I send email to alias ciao@mrtsolutions.it from me@mrtsolutions.it, I correctly receive the mail in mymail@gmail.com, but if i send an email from an external domain (user@gmail.com) to alias ciao@mrtsolutions, i can't receive the mail in mymail@gmail.com.

My mail.err is empty.

My mail.info when i send from internal:

```
May 17 11:53:44 server postfix/smtpd[25525]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 17 11:53:44 server postfix/smtpd[25525]: 629403F011: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 17 11:53:44 server postfix/cleanup[25528]: 629403F011: message-id=<64dc25b5c034c5ce4e9660e32584a687@mrtsolutions.it>
May 17 11:53:44 server opendkim[25876]: 629403F011: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mrtsolutions.it)
May 17 11:53:44 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 629403F011: from=<lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it>, size=14306, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 17 11:53:44 server spamd[17463]: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:57908 to port 783, fd 5
May 17 11:53:44 server spamd[17463]: spamd: setuid to spamd succeeded
May 17 11:53:44 server spamd[17463]: spamd: processing message <64dc25b5c034c5ce4e9660e32584a687@mrtsolutions.it> for spamd:5555
May 17 11:53:44 server spamd[17463]: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: ns17.ovh.net
May 17 11:53:44 server spamd[17463]: dns: new_dns_packet: domain is utf8 flagged: dns17.ovh.net
May 17 11:53:46 server dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it>, method=PLAIN, rip=149.202.56.54, lip=149.202.56.54, mpid=25532, TLS, session=<gfa0WxKJ1pGVyjg2>
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/smtpd[25525]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
May 17 11:53:46 server dovecot: imap(lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it): Logged out in=14171 out=658
May 17 11:53:46 server spamd[25533]: util: setuid: ruid=5555 euid=5555 rgid=5555 5555 egid=5555 5555
May 17 11:53:46 server spamd[17463]: spamd: clean message (0.7/5.0) for spamd:5555 in 2.0 seconds, 14405 bytes.
May 17 11:53:46 server spamd[17463]: spamd: result: . 0 - ALL_TRUSTED,DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08,HTML_MESSAGE,URIBL_BLOCKED scantime=2.0,size=14405,user=spamd,uid=5555,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=57908,mid=<64dc25b5c034c5ce4e9660e32584a687@mrtsolutions.it>,autolearn=no autolearn_force=no
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/pipe[25529]: 629403F011: to=<ciao@mrtsolutions.it>, relay=spamassassin, delay=2.2, delays=0.08/0.02/0/2.1, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 629403F011: removed
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/pickup[24507]: 850873F013: uid=5555 from=<lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it>
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/cleanup[25528]: 850873F013: message-id=<64dc25b5c034c5ce4e9660e32584a687@mrtsolutions.it>
May 17 11:53:46 server opendkim[25876]: 850873F013: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mrtsolutions.it)
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 850873F013: from=<lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it>, size=15090, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 17 11:53:46 server clamsmtpd: 10002B: accepted connection from: 127.0.0.1
May 17 11:53:46 server spamd[17452]: prefork: child states: II
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/smtpd[25538]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/smtpd[25538]: AD3F63F011: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/cleanup[25528]: AD3F63F011: message-id=<64dc25b5c034c5ce4e9660e32584a687@mrtsolutions.it>
May 17 11:53:46 server opendkim[25876]: AD3F63F011: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=mrtsolutions.it)
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: AD3F63F011: from=<lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it>, size=15689, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 17 11:53:46 server clamsmtpd: 10002B: from=lorenzo.martini@mrtsolutions.it, to=ciao@mrtsolutions.it, status=CLEAN
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/smtp[25536]: 850873F013: to=<ciao@mrtsolutions.it>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.39, delays=0.06/0.03/0.08/0.22, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as AD3F63F011)
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/smtpd[25538]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
May 17 11:53:46 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 850873F013: removed
May 17 11:53:47 server postfix/smtp[25540]: AD3F63F011: to=<lorenzomartini123@gmail.com>, orig_to=<ciao@mrtsolutions.it>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.140.27]:25, delay=0.69, delays=0.22/0.02/0.11/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1558086827 k12si6047671wru.260 - gsmtp)
May 17 11:53:47 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: AD3F63F011: removed
```

My mail.info when i send from external:

```
May 17 11:57:29 server postfix/smtpd[25644]: connect from mail-it1-f172.google.com[209.85.166.172]
May 17 11:57:30 server policyd-spf[25649]: prepend Received-SPF: Pass (mailfrom) identity=mailfrom; client-ip=209.85.166.172; helo=mail-it1-f172.google.com; envelope-from=lorenzomartini123@gmail.com; receiver=<UNKNOWN>
May 17 11:57:30 server postfix/smtpd[25644]: 17B713F011: client=mail-it1-f172.google.com[209.85.166.172]
May 17 11:57:30 server postfix/cleanup[25650]: 17B713F011: message-id=<CAAyxRvbY-MZHHgvQc=2Fm3P9djtyPzS9vzDAN63papNgpp6BRg@mail.gmail.com>
May 17 11:57:30 server opendkim[25876]: 17B713F011: mail-it1-f172.google.com [209.85.166.172] not internal
May 17 11:57:30 server opendkim[25876]: 17B713F011: not authenticated
May 17 11:57:30 server opendkim[25876]: 17B713F011: DKIM verification successful
May 17 11:57:30 server opendkim[25876]: 17B713F011: s=20161025 d=gmail.com SSL
May 17 11:57:30 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 17B713F011: from=<lorenzomartini123@gmail.com>, size=3257, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 17 11:57:30 server spamd[17463]: spamd: connection from ::1 [::1]:57968 to port 783, fd 5
May 17 11:57:30 server spamd[17463]: spamd: setuid to spamd succeeded
May 17 11:57:30 server spamd[17463]: spamd: processing message <CAAyxRvbY-MZHHgvQc=2Fm3P9djtyPzS9vzDAN63papNgpp6BRg@mail.gmail.com> for spamd:5555
May 17 11:57:30 server postfix/smtpd[25644]: disconnect from mail-it1-f172.google.com[209.85.166.172] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=7
May 17 11:57:31 server spamd[25653]: util: setuid: ruid=5555 euid=5555 rgid=5555 5555 egid=5555 5555
May 17 11:57:32 server spamd[17463]: spamd: clean message (-0.1/5.0) for spamd:5555 in 1.8 seconds, 3323 bytes.
May 17 11:57:32 server spamd[17463]: spamd: result: . 0 - DKIM_SIGNED,DKIM_VALID,DKIM_VALID_AU,FREEMAIL_FROM,HTML_MESSAGE,SPF_PASS scantime=1.8,size=3323,user=spamd,uid=5555,required_score=5.0,rhost=::1,raddr=::1,rport=57968,mid=<CAAyxRvbY-MZHHgvQc=2Fm3P9djtyPzS9vzDAN63papNgpp6BRg@mail.gmail.com>,autolearn=ham autolearn_force=no
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/pipe[25651]: 17B713F011: to=<ciao@mrtsolutions.it>, relay=spamassassin, delay=2.4, delays=0.62/0.02/0/1.8, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via spamassassin service)
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 17B713F011: removed
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/pickup[24507]: 325873F013: uid=5555 from=<lorenzomartini123@gmail.com>
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/cleanup[25650]: 325873F013: message-id=<CAAyxRvbY-MZHHgvQc=2Fm3P9djtyPzS9vzDAN63papNgpp6BRg@mail.gmail.com>
May 17 11:57:32 server opendkim[25876]: 325873F013: no signing table match for 'lorenzomartini123@gmail.com'
May 17 11:57:32 server opendkim[25876]: 325873F013: DKIM verification successful
May 17 11:57:32 server opendkim[25876]: 325873F013: s=20161025 d=gmail.com SSL
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 325873F013: from=<lorenzomartini123@gmail.com>, size=3826, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 17 11:57:32 server clamsmtpd: 10002C: accepted connection from: 127.0.0.1
May 17 11:57:32 server spamd[17452]: prefork: child states: II
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/smtpd[25658]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/smtpd[25658]: 5A3193F011: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/cleanup[25650]: 5A3193F011: message-id=<CAAyxRvbY-MZHHgvQc=2Fm3P9djtyPzS9vzDAN63papNgpp6BRg@mail.gmail.com>
May 17 11:57:32 server opendkim[25876]: 5A3193F011: no signing table match for 'lorenzomartini123@gmail.com'
May 17 11:57:32 server opendkim[25876]: 5A3193F011: DKIM verification successful
May 17 11:57:32 server opendkim[25876]: 5A3193F011: s=20161025 d=gmail.com SSL
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 5A3193F011: from=<lorenzomartini123@gmail.com>, size=4061, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 17 11:57:32 server clamsmtpd: 10002C: from=lorenzomartini123@gmail.com, to=ciao@mrtsolutions.it, status=CLEAN
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/smtp[25656]: 325873F013: to=<ciao@mrtsolutions.it>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10026, delay=0.4, delays=0.06/0.03/0.08/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 5A3193F011)
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/smtpd[25658]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1] ehlo=1 xforward=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=6
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 325873F013: removed
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/smtp[25660]: 5A3193F011: to=<lorenzomartini123@gmail.com>, orig_to=<ciao@mrtsolutions.it>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.184.26]:25, delay=0.63, delays=0.24/0.02/0.2/0.17, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1558087052 r193si6247994wmf.54 - gsmtp)
May 17 11:57:32 server postfix/qmgr[29019]: 5A3193F011: removed
```

Comment: The log file clearly says that the mail was successfully delivered. Have you looked into the spam folder in your GMail account? My guess is that it was put there since you send a mail claimed to be from gmail from your server even though you are not owner of the gmail.com domain. Typical problem with SPF and mail forwarding but unrelated to DKIM.

Comment: Yes, i also checked spam folder but no mail...

Comment: But you can clearly see in the log files that the mail was successfully delivered to gmail's mail server - look for 5A3193F011.

Comment: Is there a way to forward the e-mail changing the from field maybe setting an internal mail as it? And set as reply-to the mail address of original mail?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/811245/how-to-configure-postfix-to-force-from-field-but-leave-reply-to-alone and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/248107/adding-reply-to-header-for-simple-postfix-mailing-list