# How do I manually unmask a service in linux?

Tags: systemd, fedora, systemctl, mask, unmask

When `systemctl unmask name.service` responds that it has succeeded but it didn't actually succeed, what do you do?!

You can see my **serious** but surface-level problem [here.](https://serverfault.com/questions/1146784/postfix-service-was-working-after-reboot-says-failed-to-start-postfix-service)

So far as I've found so far, there's NO information on how to MANUALLY dig one's way out of this situation. And I need a solution *NOW!*

What am I supposed to do, REINSTALL FROM SCRATCH?! I didn't do anything obviously wrong to create this: the system did this on its own because it was "unhappy." ...I get it, computers have zero intelligence, artificial or otherwise, it just obeys commands and the commands react to data: I need to understand the structure of the `systemd` web of files and links so I can recreate what was here before the system did something silly! However, I'm in a "system down" situation (the email is non-functional on a mail server!), so the "crib notes" version is ideal.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you already solved it in the meantime. Please don't repost your question, instead edit it to include more information is it is not answered.